# Sharing interesting information?

Tags: discussion

I was thinking about sharing interesting information (The [philpaper survey](http://philpapers.org/surveys/results.pl) came to my mind) concerning philosophy, and whether it is in the scope of this site and if so, where the right place would be to put it.

Some options that I thought about:

Posting on meta - this might violate the term and idea of a Q&A site

Posting a question about whatever information you want to share and answering it on your own - might violate terms again

Posting in chat - is probably ok, but is less visited

What are your thoughts on this?

Comment: Chat definitely seems the "most right" but that said this ultimately seems to point to activating a regular site "feed" (I might note a few betas have community blogs...)

Comment: We could place them in chat (which would encourage more chat usage which is good) and use the site banner maybe to point out good content from time to time, perhaps?

Comment: @stoicfury Is the "banner" this community bulletin I see on the right hand side? If so, then I think chat+community bulletin notice would be a nice way to share it.

Comment: @JosephWeissman I really don't think our site has enough contributors/participation to keep a blog going, at least not yet. But perhaps this is just my own skepticism at work.

Comment: There is some sort of top banner that I forget how to access but we used to change it from time to time for contests and stuff. Maybe @JosephWeissman remembers? Do we still have access to that?

Comment: I feel like it may have been refactored somewhat during a recent update. I'll have to take a look!

Comment: I still see it here: http://space.stackexchange.com/; "got a question about the site itself? meta.space is the place to talk about things like what questions are appropriate, what tags we should use, etc." The CSS says "system-message".
I'll ask in TL.

Comment: Alright, system messages are deprecated, but we can edit the Community Bulletin.

Comment: @stoicfury Can the community bulletin display chat messages and not just regular or meta posts?

Comment: Yes, supposedly. Let's try it :D \*edit\* I updated it with a topic. It works fine. Normally it's for future events but we can use it for this if desired, I see no issue with that. The question is, how do we nominate which discussion are worthy of inclusion, and which are not? Anyone can suggest a topic, but only diamond mods can post events, as far as I know.

Comment: Just for clarification, the place to suggest a featured information is the Symposium(chatroom)?